# Re-adjust coordinate system in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bounds

I am developing an iOS game in portrait mode using Xcode with Swift, and I have found that in my GameScene() class, the bottom of my screen has the Y-Value of about 95, and the top of my screen has the Y-Value of about self.size.height - 95. The left and right bounds are 0 and self.size.width respectively, so no problem there. Is there a way I can fix my coordinate system so this doesn't happen? (e.g. make the bottom left corner (0,0) and the top right (self.size.width, self.size.height)). Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this isnt possible

Comment: There isn't a way to make self.size.height adjust depending on what device you're running it on?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @NETscape: How does this not answer the question "*Is there a way I can fix my coordinate system so this doesn't happen?"*